# try to vote up, and get "vote is too old to change"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, locked-votes

I am trying to vote https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741548/stopping-pirates/2741595#2741595 , which has no vote of mine on it, and I constantly get "Vote too old to be changed..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design, but..

Based on all the "vote too old" feedback, I modified the text to make the timed vote locking a bit more clear:

> #### You last voted on this question
>
> #### Mar 28 at 7:55
>
> #### Your vote is now locked in
>
> #### unless this question is edited

Where "question" and "answer" are substitutions.

Comment: tnx - much clearer now and will save some band width on Meta...

Answer (score 3):

Did you vote on it and take it back?

That counts as a "vote that cannot be changed"

Comment: Ah, thats good to know. I hadn't realized that voting and then un-voting still counted.

Comment: That's just plain stupid!